# Having trouble with Inheritance and Generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a class, and I declare it like this:

```
public class WhereOrCondition<T> : WhereCondition<T>
```

The generic type `T` is the same for both classes. I am not sure how to declare my classes correctly so that the Generic type used for `WhereOrCondition` is also used in `WhereCondition`.

Declaring my class in this way gives me the following error:

`Error  1   The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'BrainStorm.WhereCondition<T>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'BrainStorm.DatabaseObject'.`

Any ideas on how I can declare my class correctly?

EDIT

The `WhereCondition` class is declared like so:

```
public class WhereCondition<T> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> where T : DatabaseObject
```

Comment: What's `BrainStorm.DatabaseObject`, and how are you instantiating the generic subclass in your calling code?

Comment: what is the definition of WhereCondition<T>?

Comment: Isn't by a chance `WhereCondition` constrained with `where T: BrainStorm.DatabaseObject` ...? If that's the case, other one need same constraint too.

Comment: Ive added the class declaration for WhereCondition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put the same where condition on `WhereOrCondition<T>` so it looks like

```
public class WhereOrCondition<T> : WhereCondition<T> where T: DatabaseObject
```

The rule is a where clause on a sub class must be the same or more restrictive than a where clause on a base class.

What this says is `WhereOrCondition<T>` has `WhereCondition<T>` for a sub class and `T` must be a `DatabaseObject` (or a subclass).

Your code in the comment `public class WhereAndCondition<T> where T: WhereCondition<T>` is something completly different. That says that `T` must be a `WhereCondition<T>` which cannot be true.

Comment: Sorry, Im still a little confused. Right now i have it like this `public class WhereAndCondition<T> where T: WhereCondition<T>`. But it still is saying thats not right.

Comment: @user489041 updated (not sure where `WhereAndCondition<T>` came from)

Answer (score 1):

Adding code for Ray's answer:

```cs
public class WhereOrCondition<T> : WhereCondition<T> where T : DatabaseObject { }

public class WhereCondition<T> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> where T : DatabaseObject
{
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetEnumerator() { }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class DatabaseObject { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough code for anyone to really determine what you are trying to accomplish. Let me illustrate.

If you mean "when I create a derived class and then 'cast' as its parent class, I want T to be equal", the code you have thus far appears to fit the measure. Supposing ...

```
public class WhereCondition<T>
{
}

public class WhereOrCondition<T> : WhereCondition<T>
{
}

public class DatabaseObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

You can now use parent and child classes and, in most cases, cast up and down to your heart's content. And, the inner object will be the same.

The only thing I can think of that might cause issue is if you are not really keeping things "generic" and you have typed T in one of the classes, by adding "where T : objectType".

Am I missing something?